# Boyer Moore Search doesn't deliver all the results a native memcmp search delivers

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, memory

I am currently pattern scanning the data a function called `F` returns. The return value is a byte array with the size`65000`

My pattern is `3000` bytes long

I originally used a basic memcmp method to do the pattern scanning:

```
uintptr_t searchPatternInMemory(const Data& pattern, const unsigned char* startAddress, const unsigned char* endAddress) {
    if (startAddress == nullptr) return 0;
    for (uintptr_t address = (uintptr_t)startAddress; address < (uintptr_t)endAddress - pattern.siglen + 1; ++address) {
        if (std::memcmp((const void*)address, (const void*)(pattern.bytes.data()), pattern.siglen) == 0) {
            return address;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some basic explanation:
`pattern.siglen` is the pattern length which is 3000 as stated above.
`pattern.bytes` are the actual bytes in the pattern

The function that returns the `65000` bytes array gets executed continuously with an always different content.

This searchPatternInMemory always finds 44 occurrences in 900000 arrays returned by `F`.
Since the result of finding 44 occurrences is correct, the algorithm is very slow.

So I came up with an implementation of the Boyer Moore algorithm:

```
uintptr_t BoyerMooreSearch(const Data& pattern, const unsigned char* startAddress, const unsigned char* endAddress) {
#undef max
    if (startAddress == nullptr) return 0;
    size_t patternLength = pattern.siglen;
    if (patternLength == 0) return 0;
    std::vector<int> badCharTable(256, -1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < patternLength; ++i) {
        badCharTable[pattern.bytes[i]] = i;
    }
    size_t index = patternLength - 1;
    while (index < (size_t)(endAddress - startAddress)) {
        const unsigned char* text = startAddress + index;
        int j = patternLength - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && text[j] == pattern.bytes[j]) {
            --j;
        }
        if (j < 0) {
            return (uintptr_t)text;
        }
        int badCharShift = j - badCharTable[text[j]];
        index += std::max(1, badCharShift);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All the rest of the code stays the same. I just changed the searchPatternInMemory function to the BoyerMooreSearch function.

Here comes the problem:
This BoyerMooreSearch always only finds 32 occurrences in 900000 arrays returned by `F`.

This means that the code seems to work while being "unstable" or anything else i can't find out.

My question: Does anyone see a rookie mistake or is it the nature of the Boyer Moore to not work in this specific case?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Ran the program dozens of times and always

44 occurrences for searchPatternInMemory
and
32 occurrences for BoyerMooreSearch

i also tried the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm but this one was very very slow!

Comment: Related: C++ has provided Boyer-Moore Algorithm for pattern matching; see [std::search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) **in C++17** for more information.

Comment: Okay I will try that next. But it is nothing with the nature of boyer Moore?

Comment: For one thing, you never look at `startAddress[0]`, the very first character. That can't be right.

Comment: Taking a step back; one of the points of Boyer-Moore is that the pattern only needs to be pre-processed once, and then searched for repeatedly. You discard this advantage, by pre-processing on every search. This is a pessimization (doesn't affect correctness though, so it's not the immediate cause of your problem).